# C# phonetic spelling -- "cee sharp" vs. "see sharp"

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The title more or less says it: is there a reason why the C# [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) is using "cee" instead of "see"? In English, there's less phonetic ambiguity with "see"; whereas, "cee" could, in some obscure case, be pronounced "kee".

Comment: `C# (pronounced see sharp) is...` I think someone fixed it

Comment: I honestly thought about doing it myself, but I preferred a paper trail given my low reputation :).

Comment: Why not simply `C sharp`?

Comment: I thought it was pronounced "dee flat".

Comment: I think "see" is appropriate for an unambiguous *pronunciation* guide (as provided on the tag wiki), and I think "[cee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cee)" is more correct for use in a formal lexical expansion.

Comment: Does anyone else find it odd that C# is pronounced "see sharp" but C++ is pronounced "sea plus plus"?

Comment: @Phoenix Together: See dee flat, sharp... something.

Comment: @Bill Then how do you pronounce C++0x?

Comment: @Shibumi ["Sea plus plus Oh Ex"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1355678/561731)

Comment: It's pronounced "see octothorpe."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, and changed.

(The original pronunciation guide came from [C#'s Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29). Depending on the change's reception here, and some amateur linguistics research, I might edit that article as well.)

Comment: Is it necessary to have `see`? Isn't `C` sufficient? I mean, I don't C how you could pronounce it differently...

Comment: I suppose it's no mistake that proponents of simplifying the English alphabet often suggest removing 'c'. 'k' can take the phonetic place of the 'c' in candle (for example) without a loss of meaning.

Comment: @yoda Well, if we have to say '#' is really "sharp", then do we just say "C sharp"? I guess that's reasonable, but I like to go full phonetic if I'm going to be going phonetic at all.

Comment: @yoda: depends on the (spoken) language, I suppose. In English, you're right. Others, maybe not.

Comment: @Shibumi The confusion between `c` and `k` occurs only in words... a letter is atomic. I don't see how it can be confused with `k`. Also the `#` for sharp is necessary, because `#` is **NOT** the sharp sign. It is called either the hash symbol or pound symbol or number sign in different countries. The actual sharp sign is `♯` and `#` is a common substitute for it

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I thought this was all supposed to be English? If not, you'll have to further clarify how `see` is pronounced then... For a German interpreting that into English, `see` would be `say`. I don't mean to be kicking up the dust over something simple, but since this was brought up, it might be simpler to go with the bare minimum necessary once and for all

Comment: @yoda Understood, re: the reason for "sharp". The problem with using the English alphabet to produce phonetic pronunciations of other stuff is that the phonetic, made-up words fall victim to the same _pronunciation_ ambiguity that regular words do. In this case, I think the question is, as you've suggested, between "see sharp" and "C sharp".

Comment: @yoda: yeah, this is a bit of a can of worms. I believe "see" is a better pronunciation guide than "cee", especially since the former is a word in English, but I no longer think I should've made such a minor change. I won't be hurt if it changes to *C*, or is removed entirely.

Comment: Changing it now from see to c would itself be a "too minor" change.  It's fine the way it is.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Score! I made it in before the guilt set in.

Comment: Wouldn't the Spanish say "thee" if it was "cee"?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta just to grow the can of worms, "cee" is also a word in English - it is the name of the letter C. :)