# Why did I get a notification of this comment?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When exactly do I get comment notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications)

I received a notification of [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140441/c-phonetic-spelling-cee-sharp-vs-see-sharp#comment396423_140441), but neither my name `@ajax333221` appears anywhere on it, nor it is my question/answer.

Why this happened? Was this expected to happen?

Comment: from duplicate: "If you are the only user to comment on a post, and its author posts a comment without an @notification, you will be notified."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were the only person to have commented on the post at that time, so the system assumes the asker posted his comment in reply to yours, and notifies you of the comment just in case.

Comment: +1 thanks. However, I don't like assumptions, if I have learnt something valuable in my life is to never make an assumption unless strictly necessary. This one was right, but I am sure it will fail around 1/15 when people just comment additional instructions or updates

Comment: ... but after analyzing it, maybe 14 guys happy and 1 annoyed isn't the end of the world. I think I even like this feature